# WSO2 API Manager - 2..6.0

Tags: wso2, api-manager

We currently started using WSo2 API Manager load balance (LB) option for microservices High Availability.

1. Is it a good idea to use WSO2 LB? Or Instead of WSO2 LB, should we opt for Nginx? (which we also use for other LB requirements.)
2. Will the performance of WSO2 API Manager degrade if we choose to use WSO2 LB?

Any recommended links that we can follow to do the WSO2 LB settings? Our current configuration is causing Heap space issues and we are suspecting our "Advanced Endpoint Configuration". We want to have endpoint suspension if something goes wrong with one of the Micro service VM's. It would be great if someone is kind enough to share the recommended configs for production use case.

Best Regards,
Rithesh

Comment: Your question is somewhat confusing. What do you mean by WSO2 LB. There is no such product at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it a good idea to use WSO2 LB? Or Instead of WSO2 LB, should we opt for Nginx? (which we also use for other LB requirements.)

I believe the WSO2 LB is considered obsolete and there is really no reason why not to use anything else (nginx, httpd, haproxy,..). Even there is NGINX config somewhere on WSO2 docs site, just search for it

> Our current configuration is causing Heap space issues and we are suspecting our "Advanced Endpoint Configuration".

Without any more "advanced" information, such as profiling, it is impossible to say what is your problem.  The cause could be some custom endpoints, logging the payload, transformations, ...

Just setting the advanced properties won't cause OOM

> recommended configs for production use case

The defaults are just find for most of production use cases.  Without more information you will get only opinions